# Execute a .exe or .bat files with HTML code in Node Webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, batch-file, node-webkit

I'm using Node Webkit, and I'd like to have an HTML file that execute local files such `.exe` or `.bat`, instead of downloading it.

I tried to use this in the HTML file (index.html)  :

```
<a href="installer/setup.exe" >setup</a>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Cleaned up english and grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get some luck with this:

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Shell, though I'm unsure if it relates to running executables.

Answer (score 0):

I do this as part of my crossplatform screenshot [utility](https://github.com/teak/Pussh) built in nwjs. You can do this with the `child_process` module. You would just need to run something similar to the following on load:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec(path.join(process.cwd(), 'path', 'to', 'exe'), function(error, stdout) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

The related documentation can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).